# How to change styles for Gallery widget on Android?

Tags: android, themes, gallery

Is there a way to change styles for Gallery? For example, borders, animation speed. Maybe there is list of predefined themes?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Or how to change shadow of the selected item in Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

There´s no predefined Styles for the gallery widget, but you can achieve all of that with an [Animation](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg100685.html), for example the Shadow, changin the alpha of the item selected.

to control the speed check this wonderful [example](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg100685.html)

Comment: Thanks for this example. But I still want to change styles of Gallery.